# RedirectToAction from JSON Form Submission

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I'm uploading a file via a form with the following script tag:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateCompResponse", "Surveys", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", onsubmit = "return myFunction()" }))
```

Upon successful upload, the controller should RedirectToAction:

```
   return Json(new
                    {
                        redirectUrl = Url.Action("CreateBenefitSummary", "Surveys"),
                        isRedirect = true
                    });
```

In the view, I'm handling the function as follows (I copied and pasted this from another SO post, as I don't know JavaScript):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    success: function(json) {
    if (json.isRedirect) {
        window.location.href = json.redirectUrl;
    }
}
</script>
```

Rather than returning my desired controller action, it returns a JSON string:

```
{"redirectUrl":"/Surveys/CreateBenefitSummary","isRedirect":true}
```

How can I get this to redirect to the proper action?

Thanks!

Comment: Your code suggests you are using ajax to upload the file. The whole point of ajax is to stay on the **same** page. To use ajax and then redirect makes no sense. Just make a normal submit and use `return RedirectToAction(..)` in the POST method (and the fact you see that result means you are actually making a normal submit anyway - probably because you did not cancel the normal submit)

Comment: @StephenMuecke If the upload was unsuccessful it would be useful to stay on the same page. If you submit a regular POST you would have to show the error on a new page. It would be intuitive to be able to control what happens on an error and redirect if it is successful.

Comment: You ajax call is missing. But if you set `dataType: 'json'` then it will parse it as JSON data instead of as a string. Another way to get around this is if your server would send a content type back in the response headers.

Comment: @kezi, OP is wanting to redirect as clearly stated in the question (and if there are `ModelState` error, you return the view so the messages are displayed!)

Comment: @StephenMuecke "Upon successful upload" they want to redirect. This doesn't mean you can't use AJAX. A regular POST would make the page blank and disrupt the flow. This is the reason people use AJAX. When that `ModelState` error occurs they can display those errors while keeping the user on the same page. Simple logic. This is done on tons of popular sites: Google Drive, Facebook, File Upload Sites, etc...

Comment: @kezi. The reason people use ajax is to stay on the same page. It is nonsense to use ajax when you want to redirect. (and OP **is** making a normal submit in addition to an ajax call, and as a result is redirecting to a new page that shows the `JsonResult`)

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Html.BeginForm` which means that the `ActionResult` you expect is in the PostBack. The way `return Json` will work is if you use `Ajax.BeginForm` and pass the function name to it for `onsuccess`. You should be doing this:

`@using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateCompResponse", "Surveys", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "onSuccess",HttpMethod = "Post" }))`

And your function should be

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onSuccess(json) {
    if (json.isRedirect) {
        window.location.href = json.redirectUrl;
    }
}
</script>
```

If you want to use PostBack then you can use `RedirectToAction` within the processing controller action to check if the upload is successful or not based on the result you can use the above mentioned `return RedirectToAction` or `return View()`